# Signing .EXE executables for free (CAcert)

Tags: windows, executable

I am developing some freeware applications. Mostly they are written in Java to make them run on multiple systems. Meanwhile I have some thousand users and so it makes a lot of fun.

To make the Java apps easier to run under Windows, I also create executable wrappers using launch4j and installer applications using inno setup.

Now I have problem, because of Windows 8. In former Windows versions the OS just showed up a message by trying to start such an executable which was saying that the exe file comes from an "unknown" vendor. In Windows 8 they made it even harder. There is something like "Windows protected you from this dangerous application!".

So I am highly interested in signing my apps. But I am not willing to pay anything for this as I offer my software for free. Using Google I found the "CAcert" project that allows people to create free certificates. But I haven't found detailed information about the following questions:

- can I create certificates to sign executables?
- can I create certificates using my company name?

Is there anyone familiar with CAcert?
Or has anyone another hint to solve my problem?

thanks a lot...

Comment: I've worked with CACert to implement an HTTPS website. It's computer generated, which is why it'll only save the information about the company name. I can't help you with the signing bit though.

Comment: You have to be "validated" by a "known" certificate authority (CA). Of course, *you* are *not* a "known" CA. If anyone could sign anything on his/her own, that would defeat the whole purpose of signing. "known" CAs don't work for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use use a CAcert certificate to sign your code, but it won't help you. That's because the OS doesn't install the CAcert root certificate.

If you want to stop your users seeing these messages you'll need to obtain a commercial certificate.

Comment: Damn. This is a shame for all free developers. What's the cheapest way to get such a commercial certificate? Is it paid once or do i have to pay it every year and/or for every new version of my software? What is meant by "sign the code" - it's just the signing of an binary?

Comment: @Thomas Generally, you're on a subscription for a code-signing cert. You can generally select how long you want the cert to be good for, and you get more of a discount for a longer length of time. But they do expire.

Comment: You are going to need to pay a subscription. You should find something for around $100/yr