# How do I turn my chess engine into an executable file

Tags: java, command-line-interface, exe, launch4j, uci

I have this chess engine i wrote in java. Thing is, I need to make a exe application that can take commands following a certain protocol (UCI). Ive had many problems trying to get this to work, but ill keep this brief and share the most important ones.

1. Other engines pop up cmd when you click on them, mine is just a basic java CLI (Dont know if this is a problem).
2. My anti virus keeps stopping me from opening the exe. Launch4j gives me a warning telling me I should sign it to prevent this sort of thing, but I dont know what that means.

So heres the deal, I know this post is word vomit, but Im truly at a loss right now. Id like general order advice on how I should approach the problem and maybe some advice on wether i should be using launch4j in the first place.

Comment: Have you looked at GraalVM? https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/building-cross-platform-native-images-with-graalvm

Comment: I have not, ill do that right now.

Comment: Take a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530320) for some context, and into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325009) to get some idea about the steps for signing.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: The reason i wanted to make an exe in the first place is because thats the format that was suggested in the lichess documentation (I wanted to upload my bot to lichess). I wrote a bat file that executes the jar file and it worked fine. Thanks to everyone for the suggestions.